# Installing Computer Modern font on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, aur, ttf

I have tried installing Computer Modern Unicode fonts on Arch-linux using the following AUR repository [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-computer-modern-fonts/), but in vain. The installation goes smoothly and doesn't produce any errors but I still can't find the CMU-ttf fonts in the /usr/share/fonts/TTF directory. Any ideas ?

The output of `pacman -Ql ttf-computer-modern-fonts` is

```
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/fonts/
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/fonts/TTF/
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/fonts/TTF/cmex10.ttf
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/fonts/TTF/cmmi10.ttf
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/fonts/TTF/cmr10.ttf
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/fonts/TTF/cmsy10.ttf
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/licenses/
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/licenses/ttf-computer-modern-fonts/
ttf-computer-modern-fonts /usr/share/licenses/ttf-computer-modern-fonts/license.txt
```

Comment: Paste the output of `pacman -Ql ttf-computer-modern-fonts`

Comment: How are you looking for the fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ttf-computer-modern-fonts package provides the cmr10, cmmi10, cmex10, cmsy10 fonts on my system (you can try them in Gimp). If you are installing them for use with the MathML engine, Mozilla suggests to use:

```
sudo pacman -S texlive-core texlive-fontsextra
```

Or if you're looking for the full CMU* ttf package you could download it from [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern) and extract it in your TTF folder manually.

Comment: after I manually extract the fonts in /usr/share/fonts, how do I tell the system to refresh its font list in Arch-linux?

Comment: simply launch the terminal and enter the command fc-cache (however remember to extract the fonts in the TTF subdirectory)